# Read Byte Array from surface view?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-camera

Is is possible to read byte array from surface view?

Like in Camera API we have callback from `setPreviewCallback()` here in `onPreviewFrame(byte[])`

we have access of `byte` `array`. So same like can we have something directly from `SurfaceView`?

Comment: looks like you should draw onto `Bitmap` and then convert it into byte array

Comment: no nothing like...whatever rendering on surface view, i want to read that information as an bytearray.

Comment: @Shubh, how did you manage to acheive this?

Comment: @Shubendra sorry dear, it was long before. I will update here if anything found related.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer came later.

[PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/PixelCopy?hl=en) can get `byte[]` from `Surface`

Here are some sample:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

PixelCopy.request(mSurface, // which you wanna get byte[]
     mBitmap, // the byte[] in Bitmap
     mCallback,
     mHandler // which Callback will be invoke
);
```

In `Callback` you can get byte[] from `Bitmap`, just like `Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(...)`